# Loading a php file in a cordova ios app from a server

Tags: javascript, php, json, cordova, xmlhttprequest

The code works fine in the browser the images load. However in the app PHP file is loaded but the images appear broken. Any text I add to the PHP is fine just the images are broken.

Here's my PHP code.

```
<html>
<?php
include("mysqlconnect.php");

$select_query = "SELECT `ImagesPath` FROM `offerstbl` ORDER by `ImagesId` DESC";
$sql = mysql_query($select_query) or die(mysql_error());   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){

?> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<img src="<?php echo $row["ImagesPath"]; ?>" width="100" height="100"/></li>

<?php


}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code for the app in cordova.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("images").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("images").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example/view.php");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>


     <body onload="showUser()">

        <div id="images"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: When you run the php in your browser, does it work correctly?

Comment: Yes works perfectly in all browsers..

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Can you use PHP/ASP/JSF/Java/.NET with PhoneGap?

A: A PhoneGap application may only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web Sockets, etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in any language. This allows your PhoneGap app to remotely access existing business processes while the device is connected to the Internet.

[Phonegap FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/)

**L.E.:** Add this to your `php`:

```
$img = <<<EOD
<img src="{$row["ImagesPath"]}" width="100" height="100"/></li>
EOD;
```

And then change this in your `script`:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example/view.php");
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example/view.php?img=");
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp I was using this example and it seems to read the PHP fine. However all the images displayed are broken. The amount of images is correct however they cannot be viewed.

Comment: Then there's a problem with your code. Posting it might really help.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work. Is it that cordova/xcode won't allow images from an external source. Is there a setting change involved?

Comment: Where are the images stored? Is the `ImagesPath` accesible from your app? Alternatively, you might want to look at the [Phonegap File Transfer API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer).

Comment: The browser can find the images. the images are stored in a folder on the server beside the php file. The folder is global.

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide your Images on the Server - maybe with a Script in PHP which returns you the correct Image for an ID

For example:

```
getImage.php?imageID=100
```

Or just get the Image Paths from the Server to your Phonegap Application.

So you need to convert all your Images first to JSON.

With PHP you can use for an Array

```
json_encode($array)
```

The JSON Should look like

```
{
  "images": [
    "http://www.mywebsite/image1.jpg",
    "http://www.mywebsite/image2.jpg",
    "http://www.mywebsite/image3.jpg"
  ]
}
```

Then you need to Provide your JSON Data. For example your PHP Script returns an JSON Image with the Script called "getmyjson.php"

Output your Code with echo json_encode($yourJSONArray) and use

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Then with Cordova you can use

```
$.getJSON('http://www.mywebsite/getmyjson.php', 
function(data) {
var items=data.images;
```

items is an array containing your Image Paths. You can simple use them.